# Beamer multi-frame problem

Tags: beamer, slideshow

I am using Beamer and I want to create a multi-frame slide.

I want to have two items and three images on these frames. The first item is related to first image, the second item is related to the second image, but the third image is related to both previous items.

Now I can show the first two items and their images subsequently, but how can I show both items together with the third image?

The following MWE is given for more details. Please pay attention that I have the third image that should be displayed together with both items highlighted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning,mindmap,trees}

 \usepackage{xcolor}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={level distance = 24mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={level distance = 13mm}}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{gas turbine}
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \begin{enumerate}
\item<1>
thermal barrier coating

\item<2>
internal blade cooling

\end{enumerate}

\begin{onlyenv}<1>
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\center{
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{mrs_bulletin_tbcs.pdf}}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{onlyenv}
    \begin{onlyenv}<2>
    \begin{minipage}{0.95\textwidth}
    \center{
    \vspace*{0.3cm}\begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every        node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!40, align=flush center]
        \node[concept,scale=0.4]{\Large Gas Turbine Blade Cooling}
        [clockwise from=-30]
        child[concept] {
        node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large Internal Blade Cooling}
        [clockwise from=100]
        child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Jet Impingement} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Rib turbulators} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Pin-fins} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Swirl Chambers} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Dimples} }
        }
        child[concept] {
        node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large External Blade Cooling}
        [clockwise from=-90]
        child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Film Cooling} }
        }
        child[concept] {
        node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large Other Cooling Concepts}
        [clockwise from=-60]
        child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {\scriptsize Transpiration} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Water Cooling} }
       child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Steam Cooling} }
        }
        ;
        \end{tikzpicture}}
        \vspace*{0.3cm}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to make your question clearer. Can you please check if I understood it correctly? Please undo my edit if you don't like it.

Comment: ok, I check it and approve your modifications.

Comment: Off-topic, but instead of `\center{...}` simply use `\centering` (without parenthesis) inside your minipage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as off-topic supplement to [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) answer:

- since from question is not clear necessity of use of the mini pages, i remove them
- in the second image i remove all clutter (main contribution of this answer)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols, positioning, mindmap, trees}
\tikzset{
    level 1 concept/.append style={level distance = 24mm},
    level 2 concept/.append style={level distance = 13mm}
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{gas turbine}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}
    \begin{enumerate}
\item<1,3>
thermal barrier coating
\item<2,3>
internal blade cooling
    \end{enumerate}
\bigskip

\centering
\begin{onlyenv}<1>
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image.pdf}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<2>
    \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic,
every node/.style = {concept, concept color=blue!40, align=flush center,
                     scale=0.4}
                        ]

\node[scale=1, font=\Large]{Gas Turbine Blade Cooling}
    [clockwise from=-30]
    child   {
    node[font=\large] {Internal Blade Cooling}
    [clockwise from=100]
    child { node    {Jet Impingement} }
   child { node {Rib turbulators} }
   child { node {Pin-fins} }
   child { node {Swirl Chambers} }
   child { node {Dimples} }
    }
    child {
    node[font=\large] {External Blade Cooling}
    [clockwise from=-90]
    child { node{Film Cooling} }
    }
    child{
    node[font=\large] {Other Cooling Concepts}
    [clockwise from=-60]
    child { node    {Trans-\\ piration} }
   child { node {Water Cooling} }
   child { node {Steam Cooling} }
    };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{onlyenv}

\begin{onlyenv}<3>
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}
\end{onlyenv}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the result is (almost) the same as in  [samcarter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/36296/samcarter) answer.

Answer (score 4):

To highlight the items on more then one overlay, you can specify the overlays in `\item<1,3>`.

---

Off-topic:

- As already mentioned in an answer to your previous question, you don't need `xcolor` with beamer
- to make your code a bit simpler, you could change the order of `onlyenv` and `minipage`. This way you only need one `minipage`.
- Instead of `\center{...}` use `\centering`
- In case you don't have a cation, the `figure` environment is not necassary

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols,positioning,mindmap,trees}

\tikzset{level 1 concept/.append style={level distance = 24mm}}
\tikzset{level 2 concept/.append style={level distance = 13mm}}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{gas turbine}
    \setbeamercovered{transparent}

    \begin{enumerate}
        \item<1,3> thermal barrier coating
        \item<2,3> internal blade cooling
    \end{enumerate}

    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \begin{onlyenv}<1>
            \includegraphics[width=0.45\linewidth]{example-image.pdf}
        \end{onlyenv}
        \begin{onlyenv}<2>
            \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap, grow cyclic, every        node/.style=concept, concept color=blue!40, align=flush center]
                \node[concept,scale=0.4]{\Large Gas Turbine Blade Cooling}
                [clockwise from=-30]
                child[concept] {
                        node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large Internal Blade Cooling}
                    [clockwise from=100]
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Jet Impingement} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Rib turbulators} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Pin-fins} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Swirl Chambers} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Dimples} }
                }
                child[concept] {
                    node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large External Blade Cooling}
                    [clockwise from=-90]
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Film Cooling} }
                }
                child[concept] {
                    node[concept,scale=0.4] {\large Other Cooling Concepts}
                    [clockwise from=-60]
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {\scriptsize Transpiration} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Water Cooling} }
                    child { node[concept,scale=0.4] {Steam Cooling} }
                }
                ;
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{onlyenv}
        \begin{onlyenv}<3>
            \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-grid-100x100bp}
        \end{onlyenv}
    \end{minipage}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @mohammadfazli You're welcome!

Comment: `xcolor` is loaded by `beamer`

Comment: @Zarko Thank you very much for your comment, I totally missed that!

Comment: i also would use `figure` instead `minipage` and remove all `\vspace*{0.3cm}`. to my opinion the code will become more consistent and slightly shorter :-)

Comment: @Zarko From previous questions of this user I guess the minipages are necessary for RTL language.

Comment: @samcarter, then the first use of `figure` is wrong and should be replaced with `minipage` (in name of consistency :-) )

Comment: @Zarko I tried to clean up a bit...

Comment: @samcarter, far better! (+1)